# dynamic threads in c# using same method

Tags: c#, multithreading

In my example im trying to search a number in my database with using multiple threads. I create threads dynamicly but in my code its looks only last thread works is there a any mistake that i create threads or db connection?

exp: I have 6 records in my db:

2,3,5,7,11,13

db.threadCount() = 2 (it changes dynamicly for db record)

taskCount[temp] = 3 (you can think its half of db)

```
       for (int i = 0; i < db.threadCount(); i++)
            {
                int temp = i;
                threadEnds+= taskCount[temp];                 
                thereads[i] = new Thread(() => db.searchh(threadBegins,threadEnds, number, temp));
                thereads[i].Start();
                threadBegins+= taskCount[temp];
            }
```

my searchh function:

```
 public void searchh(int starting, int ending, int sitem,int id) 
   {
       int rturn=0;                     
       SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-G08P8S7\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=numbers;Integrated Security=True");
       string command = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
       SqlCommand db_command = new SqlCommand(command, conn);
       SqlDataAdapter dAdaptor = new SqlDataAdapter();
       DataSet dSet = new DataSet();
       DataTable dTable = new DataTable();          
       dAdaptor.SelectCommand = db_command;
       conn.Open();
       dAdaptor.Fill(dSet);
       conn.Close();
       dTable = dSet.Tables[0];           
               for (int i = starting; i <ending; i++)
               {

                   Console.Write(dTable.Rows[i][0] + "value" + id + "th thread\n\n");
                   if (sitem == ((int)dTable.Rows[i][0]))
                   {
                      MessageBox.Show("Test");                      
                   }
                   //Thread.Sleep(1000); 
               }


   }
```

my output:
7value 0th thread

11value 0th thread

13value 0th thread

Comment: Any reason you aren't using Tasks but try to use raw trheads? Not that this will help you at all - you are loading *all* the data from the database in each thread, in a very inefficient way, for no performance gain at all. Why don't you simply write a proper SQL statement?

Comment: Even if there *is* a valid reason to load everything in memory, partitioning and processing the data should be done *after* loading the data once. That can be done using LINQ. Nothing is going to be as fast as a single query on a table with proper indexes though

Comment: ok i load my data all at once but in this work i should use threads cuz its my homework :/